# What is a Surface

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, surfaces

Let $f$ be a differentiable function and $c$ a number, The set of points $P$ s.t $f(P)=c$ and $\nabla f(P)\ne 0$, is called a surface. (The author didn’t give any informations about the domain and the range of this function.)

Let $X(t)$ be a differentiable curve, we say that $X(t)$ lies on the surface if $f(X(t))=c$

I understand the first line of this definition, but i don’t know why $f(X(t))$ Should equal $c$, if $X(t)$ lies on this surface then $$X(t)=(x_1(t),...,x_n(t))$$
Where $(x_1(t),...,x_n(t))$ is a point on this surface

Comment: Your various functions, such as $f$ and $X$, lack any description of domain and range. Without knowing their domains and ranges, confusion reigns, and the possiblity of giving a coherent answer to your question is difficult. I strongly suggest editing your question to be clear about the domains and ranges (and, once you've done that, it might be possible for you to see for yourself that the equation $X(t)=c$ is nonsense).

Comment: Sorry i forgot that $X(t)$ is a vector @LeeMosher

Comment: That's not specific enough. What kind of vector? A vector in $\mathbb R^2$, so it has 2 components? A vector in $\mathbb R^3$, so it has 3 components? A vector in $\mathbb R^{42}$ so it has $42$ components? And similarly for the domain and range of $f$...

Comment: See the edit @LeeMosher

Comment: Context suggests your (Yassir's) author means: "Let $n > 0$ be an integer, $U$ a non-empty open subset of $\mathbf{R}^{n}$, and $f$ a continuously-differentiable real-valued function on $U$. If $c \in f(U)$ and if $\nabla f(P) \neq 0$ for all $P$ with $f(P) = c$, then the set $\{P : f(P) = c\}$ is called a _surface_." Not to put words in Lee's mouth, but that's probably the type of clarification requested. (If it matters, many would call such a set a _hypersurface_ or _codimension-one submanifold_.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A differentiable curve is just a set of points of the form X(t), continuously organized by the parameter t, where X is a map that takes a real parameter to a point.

A surface is also a set of points, and a point is said to be in the surface generated by f and c if it satisfies a condition of the form f(P)=c, where f is a function taking points to real numbers, and c is a real-valued constant.

A curve is then said to lie within a surface if all the points in the curve are also points in the surface. Since points in the curve are just points of the form X(t), the condition that the curve lies on the surface defined by f and c is just the condition that f(X(t))=c for all allowed values of the parameter t.

Please let me know if you are still stuck, I’m glad to keep helping you through this!!

UPDATE:
Just wanted to make one additional remark: In my original answer I gave some intuition for the right answer, but I never really addressed the problem with the one you gave. For the sake of making this as helpful as possible, I’d like to briefly do that now. You initially wrote X(t)=c, and this isn’t actually a well-defined statement! Remember that, for some t, X(t) is a point. On the other hand, c is a real number, and saying that X(t)=c is saying that a point is equal to a number, which isn’t a meaningful equality.

Comment: Should $X(t)$ be one degree less than the function $f$? example: if $f$ Is a $3$ dimensional function i.e $f(x,y)=z$ Then $X(t) =(x_1(t), x_2(t))$ @excitonfield

Comment: Well, if you want to keep the geometric intuition with curves and surfaces here, I would recommend thinking of functions like f(x,y) as being two dimensional, and their inputs being the entire space. Don’t treat the output like another dimension, think of it more like a color-coded plot.

Comment: Doing it this way, you’ll find that a two-dimensional function f gives rise to surfaces which are (usually) one-dimensional. Likewise, a three-dimensional function (again, usually) gives rise to two-dimensional surfaces, which are usually what we think of as surfaces. Technically, the surfaces can be of any dimension less than or equal to the number of variables the function takes as an input, (it can even have different regions with different dimensions) but usually they end up being one dimension less than the input space of the corresponding function.

Comment: The reason we don’t really talk about the pathological examples of functions which can have surfaces which aren’t really “surface-like” is because we’re usually more interested in using our knowledge about functions to study their surfaces than we are in using our knowledge of surfaces to study the functions.